# Java abstract class and method implementation

Tags: java, class, object, methods, abstract

```
package javaPrac;

abstract public class Abstract_class_method {
    
    abstract void show(); //abstract methods requires abstract class and has no method .
    
    void calculate(int x, int y)
    {
        int calc = x + y;
        System.out.println("This is the normal method in abstract class "+calc);
    }
    
//As per my knowledge there is no point of creating the main method within the abstract class as we cant able to create an object of the abstract class , so we either we need to use the extend keyword to extend it to other class or use the interface.
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abstract_class_method abobject = new Abstract_class_method() {
            
            @Override
            void show() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("This is the main method");
                
            }
        };
        abobject.show();
        abobject.calculate(10, 12);
    }

}
```

output

```
This is the main method
This is the normal method in abstract class 22
```

I am unable to understand the working of the main method as how in the main method I can able to make the object of the abstract class , correct me if I am wrong as the similar functionality is been observed when I am on working on anonymous classes in java.

Please provide explanation of the above code.
You help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't just repeat the same text twice to work around quality filters. Instead, *improve* the quality of your question. What aspect of the code do you not understand, precisely? What would you *expect* the result to be, and why?

Comment: As for the comment: "As per my knowledge there is no point of creating the main method within the abstract class as we cant able to create an object of the abstract class , so we either we need to use the extend keyword to extend it to other class or use the interface" - the `main` method is *static*. No instance is required in order to execute it.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: 22 is the result of 10+12 - that line is being printed by the `calculate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are classes that a programmer intentionally designates as "incomplete". They are usually used for convenience - i.e. to provide a quick way of building your own class on top of something existing with minimal effort, and to hold the code that would normally be shared among all subclasses.

What you are doing is:

- You have defined an abstract class, which by definition cannot be instantiated with `new()`. This class is missing a `show()` method, but provides a `calculate()` method.
- In your `main()` method you are creating an anonymous subclass of your abstract class that actually implements the missing `show()` method. It also inherits `calculate()` method from its parent class.